# Is there a way to group by a range of dates or datetimeoffset?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a bunch of data with a DateTime that's in UTC, I want to group each data by date by using `.GroupBy`, but I want to group them according to CST or EST. Is there a way to do this using EF core? I haven't been successful at finding if this is possible by using `DateTimeOffset` or `TimeSpan`.

Comment: `a DateTime that's in UTC` database date types except `datetimeoffset` have no `UTC` or `Local` indicator. You'll have to convert the timezone in SQL assuming the stored value is indeed UTC. If you care about offsets and timezones store `datetimeoffset`, don't assume UTC.

Comment: The methods of the .NET `DateTiimeOffset` and `TimeSpan` classes can only be used *after* you load the query results. If you're sure there are no DST changes in the date ranges you want you can convert the local time ranges into UTC and group using the existing data. If the ranges cross a DST change, you'll end up with some records in the wrong groups

Comment: What kind of grouping do you want to perform? Date-based reporting is a LOT easier if you create a [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) - a table with eg 20 years of precalculated dates with extra fields for year, month, week number, day of month, weekday, quarter, semester fields and any other date-related field you may need for reporting.

Comment: Did you mean group them by date?

Comment: @NetMage group them by a RANGE of dates

Comment: LINQ to EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x?

Comment: What does "group them by a RANGE of dates" actually mean? That is not how `GroupBy` works...?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `TimeZoneInfo` object representing e.g. Eastern Standard Time with the `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById` method. (Note: this depends on the OS timezone rules, which e.g. in the case of Windows do not cover all DST history.)

```
var tzest = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
```

Then you can convert any given `DateTime` `test` that has `DateTime.Kind` of `DateTimeKind.Utc` to the new timezone:

```
var testest = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(test, tzest);
```

If your `DateTime` has `Kind` as `Unspecified` you can use `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc()`:

```
var testest = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(test, tzest);
```

If `test` has `TimeZoneKind.Local`, this will throw an exception and you will need to override the `TimeZoneKind`:

```
var testest = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.SpecifyKind(test, DateTimeKind.Utc), tzest);
```

Comment: I want to be able to use .GroupBy using EF core

Comment: @JonSherman Server side or client side? What will you do with the resulting groups?